# Syntax Error related to Macro in C

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

```
#include<conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define small 0
#define big   1

#define dummy( _x_ )    \
( small > big ) ? ( printf _x_ ) : ( void( 0 ) )

int main() {  

    dummy( ( "Four is %d", 4 ) );
    getch();
    return 0; 
}
```

When I compiled above program in gcc, it is giving the error below:

> error : expected ')' before numeric constant.

I am not understanding  why I am getting it?
To me it seems everything is correct. Please help.

Comment: i don't think that will be the case, _x_ is something i will provide in program using dummy(_x_) ...so in this _x_ is     ( "Four is %d", 4 ) which is perfectly valid "printf" format..

Answer (score 2):

The `void(0)` part is a syntax error. You try to call a function named `void` with a 0 argument. This will work:

```
( ( small > big ) ? printf _x_ : (void) 0 )
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to come from your `void(0)`. I can't even compile it as a valid `C` expression/statement.

```
int main()
{
    void(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Gives:

```
error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before numeric constant
```

Just replace `void(0)` with `0`. Ternary operator alternatives are supposed to have the same type anyway.

Comment: true, is C++, not valid in C, +1

Answer (score 2):

Jens gives you the solution, but seems that you need `(void)printf` in order to skip warning:

```
warning: ISO C forbids conditional expr with only one void side [-pedantic]
```

This works without warnings:

```
#define dummy( _x_ ) \
       (small > big) ? (void)printf _x_ : (void)0
```

On the other hand `dummy( ( "Four is %d", 4 ) );` looks ugly to me, I suggest to use `__VA_ARGS__` and skip double parenthesis in your function call:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define small 0
#define big   1

#define dummy(...) \
     (small > big) ? (void)printf(__VA_ARGS__) : (void)0

int main(void)
{  
    dummy("Four is %d", 4);
    return 0; 
}
```

Or don't pass params:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define small 0
#define big   1

#define dummy (!(small > big)) ? (void)0 : (void)printf

int main(void)
{  
    dummy("Four is %d", 4);
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After the macro replacements your code changed like this-

```
int main() {

( 0 > 1 ) ? ( printf ( "Four is %d", 4 ) ) : ( void( 0 ) );
return 0;
}
```

Here the compiler doesn't know what is `void( 0 )`. It is not a valid syntax in C. So try to replace it by some other statement.

Try the following code

```
#define dummy( _x_ )    \
( small > big ) ? ( printf _x_ ) : (printf("Conditon fails!\n"))
```

or

```
#define dummy( _x_ )    \
( small > big ) ? ( printf _x_ ) : ((void) 0)
```